# Only get first item with SyndicationItem / alternatives to foreach

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, foreach, rss

I am learning about RSS feeds and I have hit a problem which I am surprised I have never had before now, it is probably a very simple answer but I can't find anything on Google. I am using SyndicationItem to get the XML items from an RSS feed but when you use foreach it takes every item, I only want to get the latest item - the code snippet is below.

```
    //Add required parsing in here
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        //put data you want parsed
    }
```

Obviously I have thought of just adding a break at the end, but this is definitely something I will need to find an answer for in the future and I would like to resolve it much cleaner than that.

So any help here would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var latest = feed.Items.OrderByDescending(x=>x.PublishDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

[`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) will order items by date descending and taking [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) item will get item with highest publish date (latest item)

`SyndicationItem` has [`PublishDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.publishdate.aspx) property

Read more about [`Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) it's very usefull creating such queries.

EDIT:

if they are sorted by `PublishDate` you can use [`LastOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) method, but if you are not 100% sure about that it's better to sort it before.

```
var latest = feed.Items.LastOrDefault();
```

EDIT2:

handle empty lists like:

```
if(!feed.Items.Any)
{
    //alert about no elements
}
```

Comment: Thank you, could you possibly explain what the (x=>x) bit means, I have seen it used like that before but have no idea what it means

Comment: @user1524116 it's lambda expression, it says that you will be getting PublishDate as property to order by

Comment: OP note: Unlike the `foreach` loop, `.First()` will throw exception if `feed.Items` is empty.

Comment: @weston good point, I was assuming that OP is checking for empty list

Comment: Maybe change to a `FirstOfDefault` with `null` check. (Rather than `.Any()` to ensure it doesn't multiple enumerate.)

Comment: @user1524116 read more about lambdas http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx